# searching for object in object variable

Tags: javascript

so i have a variable like this :

```
var userdata = {
  luk: {
    username: 'luktvpl',
    dcid: '53764947549426666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff1', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  },
  luk2: {
    username: 'luktvpl2',
    dcid: '53764947444666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff4', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf71-hee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  }

};
```

and i want to search this variable
for user with for example uuid : "k9-bf71-hee-ffcb4fececb8"
or with dcid : 53764947549426666
how can i do this in node.js
and i want it to return user (luk/luk2)

Comment: How are you trying to find it? You need to be more specific. Do want to return the UUID or DCID value for each user/object? Or are you entering the object/user name and you want that key's value to return

Comment: The documentation is your friend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Do you know how to loop over the keys and values of an object? Did you research it? Any attempt?

Comment: @Phix It's not an array.

Comment: You can combine `Object.entries()` with `Array.prototype.find()`.

Comment: `UUID: 'k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8',` I hope that's just an example as it's not a valid [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: i know i change it for this example

Answer (score 0):

Use object destructuring for this.

```
let valuesToFind = ["53764947549426666", "k9-bf71-hee-ffcb4fececb8"];

const keys = Object.keys(userData);

keys.forEach((key, index) =>{
    const {dcid, UUID} = userData[key];
    if(dcid == valuesTofind[0] || UUID == valuesToFind[1]){
         console.log(`Found user ${userData[key}`);
    }
})
```

Comment: is send an error : TypeError: userdata.forEach is not a function

Comment: I edited my answer. Forgot it was an object. Try it now

Comment: I modified it a bit but now it works. Thanks

Comment: cool. no problemo.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution i get the keys from all objects inner the one object. Then i iterate the keys and check if the UUID or dcid is in the object. then i check if the value of this keys is equal the search string / id.

```js
 const userdata = {
  luk: {
    username: 'luktvpl',
    dcid: '53764947549426666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff1', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  },
  luk2: {
    username: 'luktvpl2',
    dcid: '53764947444666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff4', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf71-hee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  }

};


let results = [];
const toSearch = "53764947444666";

Object.keys(userdata).forEach(ob => {
  for(key in userdata[ob]) {
    if(key === 'dcid' || key === 'UUID') {
      if(userdata[ob][key].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
        results.push(userdata[ob]);
        } 
    } 
  }
})


console.log("result", results)
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. i should look like this:

```
//variable with data
var userdata = {
  luk: {
    username: 'luktvpl',
    dcid: '53764947549426666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff1', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  },
  luk2: {
    username: 'luktvpl2',
    dcid: '53764947444666',
    password: '',
    email: 'luk@...',
    xp: '0',
    lastwork: '',
    lastmessage: '',
    lastmailcode: '',
    inventory: [ 'staff4', 'kawa' ],
    statusy: {},
    osiagniecia: {},
    pety: {},
    UUID: 'k9-bf71-hee-ffcb4fececb8',
    IdBezpieczenstwa: ''
  }

};
//function for searching
function DbGetBy(what,data) {
    //generate array
    const keys = Object.keys(userdata);
    //look for user with "what" that have value "data"
    return keys.find((key,index)=>userdata[key][what]== data);  
};
//search for uuid : k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8
console.log(DbGetBy("UUID","k9-bf7hhhcee-ffcb4fececb8"));
```